# problema al obtener los objetos almacenados en un arrayList en un repositorio

Tags: java

estoy haciendo una app de escritorio java con la arquitectura M.V.P por ahora simulo la base de datos en un arrayList en un repositorio

```
public class RepositorioClientes {

private static ArrayList<Cliente> listaClientes;

public RepositorioClientes() {
    this.listaClientes = new ArrayList<>();
}

public void setListaClientes(Cliente cliente) {
    this.listaClientes.add(cliente);
}

public ArrayList<Cliente> getListaClientes() {
    return this.listaClientes   
}  
}
```

el tema es que cuando quiero obtener ese arrayList me lo devuelve nulo.

ahí es donde llamo al repositorio para obtener el array list:

```
public class PresentadorTransferencias {

private VistaTransferencias vistaTransferencias;

private RepositorioClientes repositorioClientes;

public PresentadorTransferencias(VistaTransferencias vistaTransferencias) {
    this.vistaTransferencias = vistaTransferencias;
    this.repositorioClientes = new RepositorioClientes();
}
    public void inicializarCombobox() {

    for (Cliente cliente : repositorioClientes.getListaClientes()) {

        vistaTransferencias.getDesdejComboBoxTransferencia().addItem(cliente.toString());

        vistaTransferencias.getHaciajComboBoxTransferencia().addItem(cliente.toString());

    }
   }
  }
```

mi pregunta es, de que forma soluciono este problema para poder obtener los objetos guardados con anterioridad

Comment: te marca un error o que es es lo que pasa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te devuelve la lista vacía porque la estas vaciando en el constructor de la clase:

```
public RepositorioClientes() {
    this.listaClientes = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Y lo llamas al inicializar una variable de repositorio:

```
this.repositorioClientes = new RepositorioClientes();
```

Lo que debes hacer es inicializar la lista al declarar la variable estática:

```
private static ArrayList<Cliente> listaClientes = new ArrayList<>();
```